# windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style. Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, windows-8.1, gpt

I have a ASUS R500A notebook.Original OS is Windows 7 64bit.Few days ago I tried to Install Windows 8.1 64 bit version.But it failed & error message is,

> windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.

My Steps:
First i Deleted C: Partition ( Already installed windows 7 ).
Then i Formatted that partition.
Tried to install Windows 8.1 64bit.

In this hard disk i have another several partitions with Important data.

How do i Install Windows 8.1 without loosing Data from the Other partitions ?

Comment: Can you get into windows 7?

Comment: @RubanSavvy No i deleted that partition

Comment: Do you have windows 7 installation CD?

Comment: @RubanSavvy Yes

Comment: See here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn336946.aspx

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like your Win7 was installed with EFI-support enabled but your Win8.1 installation is booted using CSM (Compatibility Support Module), which fakes a BIOS and Win8.1 subsequently thinks it's bootet on a BIOS system, which requires installation on an MBR-style disk.

Try deactivating the CSM in your EFI settings (something like Boot Mode: UEFI only), that should avoid this issue.

Comment: This is the most probable cause. It is very likely that when you boot using the "Select boot device" option (in stead of letting the system automatically select the boot device) you will see 2 entries for the DVD player: EFI and legacy (==CSM). You will have to use the EFI to get Win8 to install properly.

Comment: @Tonny  In the Boot Configuration there's a Launch PXE OpROM(Controls the execution of UEFI and Legacy PXE OpROM) it's Enabled.. Now i disabled it.But still unsuccessful

Comment: Now I disabled PXE OpROM feature and try to install Windows 8.1 using bootable flash drive but still shows in the Hard disk partition step "Windows Cannot be installed to this disk.The selected disk is of the GPT partition style"

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place, PXE is »Preboot Execution Environment« and used to boot over the network.

Comment: Try enabling »UEFI boot« under the »Boot« menu in BIOS settings and watch out on boot selection menu that you select the right device in case both CSM and UEFI options appear (like HDD AHCI and HDD BIOS).

Comment: @AndreasWiese That was what I was trying to tell him.

Comment: My problem was that I did not boot the USB in UEFI mode. So the installer was not in UEFI mode. I solved it by using Rufus to create a USB that boots to UEFI.

Comment: Booting USB using UEFI did the job! just had to delete the partition and then it used a gpt to do the job. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 7 installation CD then Follow the steps bellow..

Boot Windows 7 DVD, click Repair your computer when you see this screen:

[image]

Then select Command Prompt..

[image]

In command prompt type `diskpart` to enter the utility.

1. Type `select disk #` replacing "#" with the drive number of the one
   you wish to format. To see a list of disks, type `list disk`.
2. Type `clean`. This deletes all volumes from the drive.
3. Type `convert mbr` to convert the disk to mbr.
4. `convert gpt` to revert back to GPT. (Optional step)

Attribution : [Mosses](https://superuser.com/users/201262/moses) Source [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/642420/tools-to-convert-gpt-to-mbr-without-access-to-an-os)

Comment: AFAIK A disk can be of MBR or GPT, a partition cannot be changed unless all the other partition is changed MBR <-> GPT. So if doing this conversion would erase all data..

Comment: Can we do anything without loosing data of other partitions ?

Comment: Can i backup other partition data ?

Comment: Yes you can back  up data by using `Clonezilla`, but you need an external drive or pendrive equivalent to the size of your backup data.. A step by step document is here http://www.maketecheasier.com/clone-drives-and-partitions-with-clonezilla/

Comment: The original question clearly states that losing existing partitions is unacceptable, but this procedure will do precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot using UEFI. Actually, your bootable DVD/USB Flash Drive should support UEFI boot.

#### Boot from DVD ROM

I guess Windows DVD ISO supports both UEFI boot and BOIS (legacy) boot, so if you are installing windows from a DVD-Drive, you should select a boot option that supports UEFI. You need to do it in the BOIS boot menu (by pressing F12 or F11 while booting the PC), or select it in the **Boot** page of the system BOIS (you may need to add required boot option).

#### Boot from USB Flash Drive

You need to create a bootable Flash drive using a tool that support UEFI boot. I highly recommend [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), as it is the best utility for creating bootable USB Flash drives. Make sure that you select **GPT partition scheme for UEFI** in the second drop down menu ("Partition scheme and target system type"). You may also need to adjust the boot setting in the system BOIS (like what I said for DVD ROM)

For more information see:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825112.aspx
- http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/04/603195/en
- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2328-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-8-a.html