# CD rom is missing when I try to reinstall

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation, reinstall

I tried to reinstall my friend's laptop by using Windows 8. After I formatted the disk, It's said something about GPT or similar which meant I couldn't do the next step. Then, I tried to refresh it but it's failed and the same thing was happened when I tried to reset it. After that, I turned off the laptop and turn it on again    but surprisingly, the CD roms was not detected,, 
is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/731693/windows-cannot-be-installed-on-this-disk-the-selected-disk-is-of-the-gpt-partit

Comment: Are you still able to see the drive in the BIOS? If so are you able to boot from another disc eg: [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: yeah, I still can see the drive but there is no CD rom or USB device detected,,
and I haven't tried to use Ubuntu Live CD yet,,

Comment: So is Windows installed and is booting fine?

Comment: honestly, I don't have any idea how to use Ubuntu Live CD because the devices is completely undetected,, BIOS just shows the drive,,
the windows was not installed yet when I tried for the first time. I only reached on formatting partition step,,

Comment: You can't see the CD/DVD drive in the BIOS at all? What make and model of laptop is this? Please update the question with that information.