# Windows cannot be installed on the disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

Is there any solution to above error without deleting my important document in other drive. I googled it and found the only solution to clean the hard like below

1. Boot from the Windows DVD
2. Click Install Now
3. At the setup screen, click Custom (Advanced)
4. Click Drive Options
5. Select the partition(s) you want to format
6. Click Format - this will delete EVERYTHING on that partition
7. Create a new partition and select a partition to install Windows on.
8. Continue with install.

When I follow these step then it will delete all my files.

So the question is how to format only c drive preserving my important document in another drive or any other way to save my datas.

Comment: To clarify: You have one hard drive (discs) with 2 partitions (c: and d:)? You don't have two separate hard drives (discs), right? [Similar to this](http://www.techwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/gpt-partition-error.jpg)

Comment: A shot in the dark: Could it be that you ran into the same issue [this OP had](http://superuser.com/a/731776/50173) where he should select something like *Boot Mode: UEFI only*

Comment: yah I had similar problem likes yours..how to solve it?

Comment: I just linked you another question. I'm not the person with that problem. Does your mainboard/laptot offer such an option like Boot mode: UEFI only? (could be named different)

Answer (score 2):

1.During the installation open cmd and type the following commands and see if it can help:
:>diskpart
:>list disk
:>select disk0
:>clean

Replace disk0 with the partition you want to format.

2.Boot from a live linux dvd/cd/usb like ubuntu then start gparted and format the required drive or if you have external storage available you can copy your data from the live boot.

Comment: 2 hints from my experience:
you can open a console with shift+f10.
you must enter "select disk 0" (not "select disk0").

Comment: Option 2 didn't work. Option 1 lists all the partition as a single disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use some flavor of network backup to push the data to some remote storage and then retrieve from the network once the disk operations are complete. There is literally 100s of ways to do this ranging from Google Drive/Dropbox to Rsync/SCP.

You installation problem may be in part because GPT is not "universally" supported in windows. Also, you'll need a UEFI bootable system if you want to boot windows from a GPT.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Windows:_32-bit_versions