# How to install windows 7 OS into external Hard disk from linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, installation, external-hard-drive

I have a linux machine installed in my computer and i have a external hard disk of 1TB inserted into linux machine.

I tried installing windows into external hard disk but i get some error like

```
you have GPT partition where windows can't be installed
```

Can i install windows os to external hard disk from LINUX

If yes please give me examples

Comment: You need to convert it to MBR partition scheme, which means you will also lose all data on that drive, see here: http://superuser.com/a/642421/168519

Comment: You can only install Windows 7 to a GPT partitioned disk if you boot it with UEFI.